# ExpoPlayer couldn't fetch url

Tags: java, android, exoplayer, android-video-player, android-developer-api

My `view` is being displayed but the link is not being fetched and played. The permission of Internet has also been added to Manifest file. The `activity_main` has also been properly placed.

```
package com.example.exoplayer;
        
        import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
        
        import android.net.Uri;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        
        import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException;
        import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory;
        import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
        import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaSource;
        import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource;
        import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.DefaultTrackSelector;
        import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView;
        import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSource;
        import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSourceFactory;
        import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util;
        
        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
            private PlayerView playerView;
            private SimpleExoPlayer player;
        
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                playerView=findViewById(R.id.playerView);
        
            }
        
            @Override
            protected void onStart() {
                super.onStart();
                player= ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this,new DefaultTrackSelector());
                playerView.setPlayer(player);
                DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
                        Util.getUserAgent(this,getString(R.string.app_name)));
                MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                      .createMediaSource(Uri.parse("http://buildappswithpaulo.com/videos/outro_music.mp4"));
                    player.prepare(videoSource);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please crosscheck with following steps or copy-paste

1. Then add internet permission in your manifest file to get video URL

manifest.xml

```
<manifest ...>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ...>

    ...

  </application>
</manifest>
```

2. 

```
//app/build.gradle
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
...
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
}
}

dependencies {
...
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.10.4'
}
```

3. 

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    Context ctx =this;
    String CONTENT_URL = "http://buildappswithpaulo.com/videos/outro_music.mp4";
    int playerID=R.id.pv_main;
    int appNameStringRes = R.string.app_name;
    startPlayingVideo(this,CONTENT_URL,playerID,appNameStringRes);


}

//
private void startPlayingVideo(Context ctx , String CONTENT_URL, int playerID, String appNameRes) {

    PlayerView pvMain = ctx.findViewById(playerID);

    //BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    //TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);        
    //TrackSelector trackSelectorDef = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
    TrackSelector trackSelectorDef = new DefaultTrackSelector();

    SimpleExoPlayer absPlayerInternal = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(ctx, trackSelectorDef);

    String userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(ctx, ctx.getString(appNameRes));

    DefaultDataSourceFactory defdataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(ctx,userAgent);
    Uri uriOfContentUrl = Uri.parse(CONTENT_URL);
    MediaSource mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(defdataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uriOfContentUrl);

    absPlayerInternal.prepare(mediaSource);
    absPlayerInternal.setPlayWhenReady(true);

    pvMain.setPlayer(absPlayerInternal);

}

private void stopPlayer(PlayerView pv,SimpleExoPlayer absPlayer){
    pv.setPlayer(null);
    absPlayer.release();
    absPlayer = null;
}
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/pv_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</FrameLayout>

Comment: I got error in `MainActivity.class` -:  in this line below ->>>>>>                                ` PlayerView pvMain = ctx.findViewById(playerID);`